# How to add rel='bookmark'?

Tags: javascript

I'm new here and I'm also not much of a programmer but I hope you guys could help me with Javascript.

You see, I have this 3rd-party script that enables bloggers blogging on Blogger to add some kind of a list of related posts on their pages. Here is the script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// takes a json feed and creates an HTML-formatted list of the elements
function RelatedPostEntries(json) {
// change the next three variables as required
var homeUrl = 'http://whatever.blogspot.com/';
var maxNumberOfPostsPerLabel = 7;
var TargetElement = 'relatedcontent-list';

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var maxPosts = (json.feed.entry.length <= maxNumberOfPostsPerLabel) ? json.feed.entry.length : maxNumberOfPostsPerLabel;

for (var i=0; i<maxPosts; i++) {
var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
var alturl;
for (var k=0; k<entry.link.length; k++) {
if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
alturl = entry.link[k].href;
break;
}
}
var li = document.createElement('li');
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = alturl;

if(a.href!=location.href) {
var txt = document.createTextNode(entry.title.$t);
a.appendChild(txt);
li.appendChild(a);
ul.appendChild(li);
}
}

for (var l=0; l<json.feed.link.length; l++) {
if (json.feed.link[l].rel == 'alternate') {
var raw = json.feed.link[l].href;
var label = raw.substr(homeUrl.length+13) + ':';
var txt = document.createTextNode(label);
var h = document.createElement('b');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(h);
div.appendChild(ul);
document.getElementById(TargetElement).appendChild(div);
}
}
}
function CodeHook(url, label, callback) {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', url + 'feeds/posts/default/-/' + label + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=' + callback);
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
}
//]]>
</script>
```

The script works fine but the problem is the original programmer has forgotten to add rel='bookmark' to his codings thus leaving us bloggers with a huge headache when it comes to SEO.

Can you guys show me where and how to add that rel attribute?

Thanks.

Comment: "bloggers blogging on Blogger"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `a.rel = 'bookmark'` after when the element is declared, around here:

```
...

var li = document.createElement('li');
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = alturl;
a.rel = 'bookmark';

...
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Thanks! This is what has been generated after adding what you have suggested; <a href="http://whatever.blogspot.com/2011/07/whatever.html" rel="bookmark">Whatever whatever</a> I guess this is correct, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = alturl;
a.rel = "bookmark";
```